# best way to compare between two-dimension integer arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I would like to know what is the best, fastest and easiest way to compare between 2-dimension arrays of integer.
the length of arrays is the same. (one of the array's is temporary array)

Comment: Sounds like a homework question?  Go with the easiest method first.  Start with one array iterate through the other for each element of the first applying your conditional check on each iteration step.  That method is very inefficient and you can likely speed things depending on the structure of the arrays (i.e. are they sorted), what you're search for, etc.  Ask yourself why its bad and what conditions would make things easier to find what you want.

Comment: you need to add a bit more definition to your question so we can help.  Do you have 2 1-D arrays or 2 2-D arrays/tables.  What are you using to store your arrays? Integer[] or an implementation of List<>?  What have you tried and why don't you like it?

Comment: When you say "compare", do you mean test for elementwise equality?  If so, `Arrays.equals` is your friend.  If by "compare" you mean something else, can you elaborate?

Comment: The purpose is just to check that the two arrays is the same that i could terminate the app.
it's two arrays of two-dimension with the same length both.

Comment: just need to see if the value is the same

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edan wrote:

> just need to see if the value is the same

If you want to check that `a[i][j]` equals `b[i][j]` for all elements, just use `Arrays.deepEquals(a, b)`.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html); it has many array utilities that you should familiarize yourself with.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

int[][] arr1;
int[][] arr2;
//...
if (Arrays.deepEquals(arr1, arr2)) //...
```

From [the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

> Returns `true` if the two specified arrays are *deeply equal* to one another. Unlike the `equals(Object[],Object[])` method, this method is appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.

Note that in Java, `int[][]` is a subtype of `Object[]`. Java doesn't really have true two dimensional arrays. It has array of arrays.

The difference between `equals` and `deepEquals` for nested arrays is shown here (note that by default Java initializes `int` arrays with zeroes as elements).

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    //...

    System.out.println((new int[1]).equals(new int[1]));
    // prints "false"

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(
        new int[1],
        new int[1]
    )); // prints "true"
    // invoked equals(int[], int[]) overload

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(
        new int[1][1],
        new int[1][1]
    )); // prints "false"
    // invoked equals(Object[], Object[]) overload

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(
        new int[1][1],
        new int[1][1]
    )); // prints "true"
```

#### Related questions

- [Java `Arrays.equals()` returns `false` for two dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721033/java-arrays-equals-returns-false-for-two-dimensional-arrays/)