# Java Arrays.equals() returns false for two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I was just curious to know - why does Arrays.equals(double[][], double[][]) return false? when in fact the arrays have the same number of elements and each element is the same?

For example I performed the following test.

```
double[][] a,  b;
int size =5;

a=new double[size][size];
b=new double[size][size];

for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    for( int j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
        a[i][j]=1.0;
        b[i][j]=1.0;
    }

if(Arrays.equals(a, b))
    System.out.println("Equal");
else
    System.out.println("Not-equal");
```

Returns false and prints "Not-equal".

on the other hand, if I have something like this:

```
double[] a,  b;
int size =5;

a=new double[size];
b=new double[size];

for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
    a[i]=1.0;
    b[i]=1.0;
} 

if(Arrays.equals(a, b))
    System.out.println("Equal");
else
    System.out.println("Not-equal");
```

returns true and prints "Equal". Does the method only work with single dimensions? if so, is there something similar for multi-dimensional arrays in Java?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Use [`deepEquals(Object[], Object[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

> Returns `true` if the two specified arrays are *deeply equal* to one another.

Since an `int[]` is an `instanceof Object`, an `int[][]` is an `instanceof Object[]`.

---

As to *why* `Arrays.equals` doesn't "work" for two dimensional arrays, it can be explained step by step as follows:

#### For arrays, `equals` is defined in terms of object identity

```
System.out.println(
    (new int[] {1,2}).equals(new int[] {1,2})
); // prints "false"
```

This is because arrays inherit their `equals` from their common superclass, [`Object`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Often we really want value equality for arrays, of course, which is why `java.util.Arrays` provides the `static` utility method `equals(int[], int[])`.

```
System.out.println(
    java.util.Arrays.equals(
        new int[] {1,2},
        new int[] {1,2}
    )
); // prints "true"
```

#### Array of arrays in Java

- An `int[]` is an `instanceof Object`
- An `int[][]` is an `instanceof Object[]`
- An `int[][]` is ***NOT*** an `instanceof int[]`

Java doesn't really have two dimensional arrays. It doesn't even really have multidimensional arrays. Java has array of arrays.

#### `java.util.Arrays.equals` is "shallow"

Now consider this snippet:

```
System.out.println(
    java.util.Arrays.equals(
        new int[][] {
            { 1 },
            { 2, 3 },
        },
        new int[][] {
            { 1 },
            { 2, 3 },
        }
    )
); // prints "false"
```

Here are the facts:

- Each argument is an `Object[]`

  - The element at index 0 is an `int[] { 1 }`
  - The element at index 1 is an `int[] { 2, 3 }`.
- There are two `Object[]` instances
- There are four `int[]` instances

It should be clear from the previous point that this invokes [`Arrays.equals(Object[], Object[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) overload. From the API:

> Returns `true` if the two specified arrays of `Objects` are equal to one another. The two arrays are considered `equal` if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. Two objects `e1`  and `e2` are considered equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.

Now it should be clear why the above snippet prints `"false"`; it's because the elements of the `Object[]` arrays are not equal by the above definition (since an `int[]` has its `equals` defined by object identity).

#### `java.util.Arrays.deepEquals` is "deep"

In contrast, here's what [`Arrays.deepEquals(Object[], Object[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) does:

> Returns `true` if the two specified arrays are *deeply* equal to one another. Unlike the `equals(Object[],Object[])` method, this method is appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.

```
System.out.println(
    java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(
        new int[][] {
            { 1 },
            { 2, 3 },
        },
        new int[][] {
            { 1 },
            { 2, 3 },
        }
    )
); // prints "true"
```

---

#### On `Arrays.toString` and `Arrays.deepToString`

It's worth noting the analogy between these two methods and what we've discussed so far with regards to nested arrays.

```
System.out.println(
    java.util.Arrays.toString(
        new int[][] {
            { 1 },
            { 2, 3 },
        }
    )
); // prints "[[I@187aeca, [I@e48e1b]"

System.out.println(
    java.util.Arrays.deepToString(
        new int[][] {
            { 1 },
            { 2, 3 },
        }
    )
); // prints "[[1], [2, 3]]"
```

Again, the reasoning is similar: `Arrays.toString(Object[])` treats each element as an `Object`, and just call its `toString()` method. Arrays inherit its `toString()` from their common superclass `Object`.

If you want `java.util.Arrays` to consider nested arrays, you need to use `deepToString`, just like you need to use `deepEquals`.

Comment: Very nicely explained... I did try to click it earlier but was asked to wait for 10 minutes :)... I just did it.

Comment: @Achilles: I try to do my best. I'm glad to help.

Comment: Indeed: solid explanation! +1

Comment: Also deepHashCode() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode(java.lang.Object[]) which is useful for creating 'value objects' where you want to implement both 'equals()' and 'hashCode()'.

Comment: Explained like a pro! Thanks for the solid explanation

Answer (score 0):

java does not actually have multidimensional arrays. Instead it has only single dimensional array and the multi d arrays will be arrays of this 1d arrays . String.equals() can be only performed to the basic , single block arrays and hence it doesn't work for multidimensional arrrays.