# Convert string into two dimensional string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I like to convert string for example :

```
String data = "1|apple,2|ball,3|cat";
```

into a two dimensional array like this

```
{{1,apple},{2,ball},{3,cat}}
```

I have tried using the `split("")` method but still no solution :(

Thanks..

Kai

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
    String data = "1|apple,2|ball,3|cat";
    String[] rows = data.split(",");

    String[][] matrix = new String[rows.length][]; 
    int r = 0;
    for (String row : rows) {
        matrix[r++] = row.split("\\|");
    }

    System.out.println(matrix[1][1]);
    // prints "ball"

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
    // prints "[[1, apple], [2, ball], [3, cat]]"
```

Pretty straightforward except that [`String.split`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes regex, so metacharacter `|` needs escaping.

#### See also

- [Regular expressions and escaping special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/regular-expressions-and-escaping-special-characters)
- [Java Arrays.equals() returns false for two dimensional arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721033/java-arrays-equals-returns-false-for-two-dimensional-arrays/)

  - Use `Arrays.deepToString` and `Arrays.deepEquals` for multidimensional arrays

---

#### Alternative

If you know how many rows and columns there will be, you can pre-allocate a `String[][]` and use a `Scanner` as follows:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(data).useDelimiter("[,|]");
    final int M = 3;
    final int N = 2;
    String[][] matrix = new String[M][N];
    for (int r = 0; r < M; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
            matrix[r][c] = sc.next();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
    // prints "[[1, apple], [2, ball], [3, cat]]"
```