# convery string into array with brackets

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following String

```
[http://images.com/1.jpg, http://images.com/2.jpg, http://images.com/3.jpg]
```

I want to store the contents of this array inside a string array or array list of type string.

I tried using .split method, but it fails mainly because the string also contains the brackets at the beginning.

Comment: May [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786777/convert-string-into-two-dimensional-string-array-in-java?rq=1) can help you.

Comment: post you input and desired output srray

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] splittedString = theString.substring(1, theString.length()-1).split(", ")
```

Notice space after comma in the split method.

Answer (score 2):

Use substring to exclude the string from the brackets:

```
mystring = mystring.substring(1,mystring.length()-1);
```

And then the split:

```
String[] myarray = mystring.split(", ");
```

Comment: You'll need a space after the comma for your ans to be 100% correct

Comment: @artfullyContrived Yes, thank you. I didn't notice the space.

Answer (score 1):

```
String arry[] = yourstr.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the first and the last characters of your String containing the brackets before using the split() method, like this :

```
yourString= yourString.substring(1, yourString.length()-1));
// do your split() method
```

Answer (score -1):

Optionally you can use `StringTokenizer`.