# What is this: [Ljava.lang.Object;?

Tags: java, arrays, class, tostring

I get this when I call `toString` on an object I received from a function call. I know the type of the object is encoded in this string, but I don't know how to read it.

What is this type of encoding called?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.Object;` is the name for `Object[].class`, the [`java.lang.Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) representing the class of array of `Object`.

The naming scheme is documented in [`Class.getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29):

> If this class object represents a reference type that is not an array type then the binary name of the class is returned, as specified by the Java Language Specification ([§13.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.1)).
>
> If this class object represents a primitive type or `void`, then the name returned is the Java language keyword corresponding to the primitive type or `void`.
>
> If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the internal form of the name consists of the name of the element type preceded by one or more `'['` characters representing the depth of the array nesting.
>   The encoding of element type names is as follows:
>
> ```
> Element Type        Encoding
> boolean             Z
> byte                B
> char                C
> double              D
> float               F
> int                 I
> long                J
> short               S 
> class or interface  Lclassname;
> ```

Yours is the last on that list.  Here are some examples:

```
// xxxxx varies
System.out.println(new int[0][0][7]); // [[[I@xxxxx
System.out.println(new String[4][2]); // [[Ljava.lang.String;@xxxxx
System.out.println(new boolean[256]); // [Z@xxxxx
```

The reason why the `toString()` method on arrays returns `String` in this format is because arrays do not `@Override` the method inherited from `Object`, which is specified as follows:

> The [`toString` method for class `Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

***Note***: you can not rely on the `toString()` of any arbitrary object to follow the above specification, since they can (and usually do) `@Override` it to return something else. The more reliable way of inspecting the type of an arbitrary object is to invoke [`getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) on it (a `final` method inherited from `Object`) and then [reflecting](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/index.html) on the returned `Class` object. Ideally, though, the API should've been designed such that reflection is not necessary (see *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 53: Prefer interfaces to reflection*).

---

#### On a more "useful" `toString` for arrays

[`java.util.Arrays`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) provides `toString` overloads for primitive arrays and `Object[]`. There is also `deepToString` that you may want to use for nested arrays.

Here are some examples:

```
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3 };

System.out.println(nums);
// [I@xxxxx

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
// [1, 2, 3]

int[][] table = {
        { 1, },
        { 2, 3, },
        { 4, 5, 6, },
};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(table));
// [[I@xxxxx, [I@yyyyy, [I@zzzzz]

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(table));
// [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

There are also `Arrays.equals` and `Arrays.deepEquals` that perform array equality comparison by their elements, among many other array-related utility methods.

#### Related questions

- [Java Arrays.equals() returns false for two dimensional arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721033/java-arrays-equals-returns-false-for-two-dimensional-arrays) -- in-depth coverage

Answer (score 1):

If you are here because of the Liquibase error saying:

```
Caused By: Precondition Error
...
Can't detect type of array [Ljava.lang.Short
```

and you are using

```
not {
  indexExists()
}
```

precondition multiple times, then you are facing an old bug:
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1342

We can try to execute an above check using bare `sqlCheck`(Postgres):

```
SELECT COUNT(i.relname)
FROM
    pg_class t,
    pg_class i,
    pg_index ix
WHERE
    t.oid = ix.indrelid
    and i.oid = ix.indexrelid
    and t.relkind = 'r'
    and t.relname = 'tableName'
    and i.relname = 'indexName';
```

where `tableName` - is an index table name and `indexName` - is an index name