# How to upcast an Object to a java.util.Map?

Tags: java, object, dictionary, casting

I have an object in my code of the type Object:
`Object o`

The class of the instance is Object: `o.getClass()` gives Object.

Now, it should be a Map! How can I upcast this to a Map?

I tried: `Map<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String,Object>)o`

But this returns:
  java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

*The instance 'o' comes from a XMLRPC request. This request does not qualify variables correctly supposedly*

Please have a look at this!?

**EDIT:**

Now I have the following issue: 
`o.getClass().getName()` gives `java.util.ArrayList`,

`o.get(0)` gives `[Ljava.lang.Object;@739e8329`,

and `o.get(0).getClass().getName()` gives `java.lang.String`.

I cannot findout what to do..

**EDIT2:**

Finally I found out what happened. The software that created this object flattened a datastructure into a String (valueOf()). So, when I printed the variable it returned a [Ljava.util.Object, which was in fact a String containing this information.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java: what is this: \[Ljava.lang.Object;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.Object` indicates the type of the object o is an array of Objects - that is `Object[]`. You cannot cast it to `Map`.

You might find it useful if took a look at: [java: what is this: [Ljava.lang.Object;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object)

You stated that `.getClass()` indicated `Object`, but was it `Object` or `[LObject`?
Compare to:

```
    Object[] array= new Object[]{};
    Object simple = new Object();

    System.out.println(array.getClass());
    System.out.println(simple.getClass());
```

which prints:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
class java.lang.Object
```

Comment: +1 but imho you should add that casting Object to Map is fine, even if you say it indirectly.

Comment: I'm now a step further: I do the following:
o.getClass().getName() --> java.util.ArrayList, and then
o.get(0) --> [Ljava.lang.Object;@8sfajb8c or so, and then
o.get(0).getClass().getName() --> java.lang.String (!!) How is that possible?

Comment: I think its just that you dont get what you expect to get.

Comment: @InsertNickHere, I think you're right.. I have to explore what I'm getting. In PHP I would use var_dump, but it is hard to do that in Java. Any ideas?

Comment: @user441174 use any IDE with a debugger (like Eclipse).  When breaking you can inspect the variable.  You'll see its type, members; pretty much anything you want to know about it.

Comment: @Joeri Hendrickx: thanks, I was using a product that is based on Eclipse and it seemed to be dissapeared. Now I switched it on, it is working much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The error clearly indicates, that `o` does not implement the `Map` interface. So it is impossible to cast this object to `Map`.

The result is an array of Objects. Maybe, the array actually holds maps. Try if this works:

```
 Object[] objects = (Object[]) o;
 if (objects != null && objects.length > 0) {
    Object object = objects[0];
    if (object instanceof Map) {
      Map map = (Map) object;
      System.out.println("Heureka!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I beg to differ on that point, Hashmap does inherit java.lang.Ojbect. Map is an interface, which I understood to be different but not the particular issue here.

Comment: @ebt - this is exactly the issue. `o` extends `Object`, that's for sure, but to be able to cast this instance to `Map`, the instance has to be an implementation of `Map` too. (Actually he's casting to `HashMap` which is not necessary and doesn't change anything)

Answer (score 2):

```
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> map = oMapper.convertValue(YOUROBJECT, Map.class);
    List<InputValues> inputValuesList = new ArrayList<InputValues>();
   for(String key : map.keySet()){
        inputValuesList.add(new InputValues(key,map.get(key).toString()) );
    }


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

InputValues class has 2 Strings.Also Jackson Dependency has to be added.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast `o` to `Map`, because it does not implement `Map` interface. Exception shows that `o` is array of `Object`s.