# Java: split() returns [Ljava.lang.String;@186d4c1], why?

Tags: java, split

And i have no idea why!

I bascially have a STRING (yes, not an array), that has the following contents:

```
[something, something else, somoething, trallala, something]
```

And i want to turn it into a String[]. So first off i substring() off the first and the last character to get rid of the brackets []. Then i use the split() function to split by comma. I tried using both "\|" and "," and "\," with the same results.

This is what i get:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@186d4c1
```

Here's the code for it. I made it into a one-liner:

```
String[] urlArr = ((matcher.group(3).toString()).substring(1, (matcher.group(3).length()-1))).split(",");
```

As you can see the first part is (matcher.group(3).toString()), and it DOES return a valid string (like the example i posted above). So i don't get why it's not working.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I clarified the code a bit:

```
String arrString = matcher.group(3).toString();
int length = arrString.length();
String[] urlArr = (arrString.substring(1, length-1)).split(",");
System.out.println(urlArr);
```

Comment: How are you getting `[Ljava.lang.String;@186d4c1`? Doing a S.O.P of `urlArr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting a valid array of `String`s, but trying to print it directly does not do what you would expect it to do. Try e.g.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(urlArr));
```

#### Update

If you want to process the parsed tokens one by one, you can simply iterate through the array, e.g.

```
for (String url : urlArr) {
  // Do something with the URL, e.g. print it separately
  System.out.println("Found URL " + url);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The output

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@186d4c1
```

is the way java prints a string array (or any array) by default (when converted to a string). You may use

```
Arrays.toString(urlArr)
```

to get a more readable version.

Comment: Alright, but how would i go about to loop through all the items? Like a foreach loop? How do i get the actual value instead of that code? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a better solution than converting it to a list to use the List's toString(), like Peter suggested. Shouldn't matter too much though since it's probably for debug only.

Comment: What do you mean by "value"? You get an array of strings which you can loop over (e.g. as you suggested by a for loop: `for (String s : urlArr) { System.out.println(s); }`).

Comment: No, it's not for debug only. The string i'm parsing is from a config file, and i need to split the values into a new array to load into the program.

Comment: But i can't loop through a string right? If i use the Arrays.toString(), it returns a string, and i can't loop through a string? See where i'm going? I might not be getting you right :/

Comment: If you're interested look here for an [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object) of the output.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `toString` on an Array, you just get the internal representation. Not that useful. Try `Arrays.toString(what comes back from split)` for something more readable.