# Unable to access String value

Tags: string, scala, collections, scala-collections

Why unable to access the String value ?

I would expect the s1 to be "a" but instead its Ljava.lang.String;@d70d7a ?

```
 val it = Iterator("(a,((a,b),1.0))")             //> it  : Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

 val s1 = it.next.replace("(" , "").replace(")" , "").split(",").toString.split(",")
                                                  //> s1  : Array[String] = Array([Ljava.lang.String;@d70d7a)
 println("s1 is "+s1(0))                          //> s1 is [Ljava.lang.String;@d70d7a
```

Comment: You probably want `mkString(",")` instead of `toString`. `toString` on an array will produce the ugly `[Ljava.lang.String;@d70d7a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go command-by-command:

```
val it = Iterator("(a,((a,b),1.0))")
// here we got iterator on one String

val s1 = it.next // "(a,((a,b),1.0))"
        .replace("(" , "") // "a,a,b),1.0))"
        .replace(")" , "") // "a,a,b,1.0"
        .split(",") // multiple lines in array: "a", "a","b","1.0"
        .toString // Array[String].toString returns what you got: Ljava.lang.String;@d70d7a
        .split(",") // one String (because there's no "," signs)
```

Maybe you should run `toList` before `toString`, because `toString` is defined in a way you expect it to be defined in this implementation of `List`:

```
val s1 = ...
        .split(",")
        .toList
        .toString
        ...
```

Maybe you should look at [Java: split() returns [Ljava.lang.String;@186d4c1], why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517704/java-split-returns-ljava-lang-string186d4c1-why) for clarification.

Comment: I wouldn't say *it's defined correctly* -- Array's definition of .toString is perfectly correct, it's just not what you would expect to see.

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I'll fix answer somehow

Answer (score 2):

`.split(",")` makes Array and `.toString` doesn't work on Array and after that you are again spliting by `.split(",")`
which i don't think helpful.

and you can also use `replaceAll` in place of multiple `replace`

```
scala>  val it = Iterator("(a,((a,b),1.0))")         
it: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala>  val s1 = it.next.replaceAll("[()]" , "").split(",")
s1: Array[String] = Array(a, a, b, 1.0)

scala> println("s1 is "+s1(0))    
s1 is a
```