# testDecodeSingleInt(com.asdf.TestDecoder): java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, object, casting, integer

When I run following code in my unit test:

```
Object parsedObject = null;
Integer i = new Integer(bb.getInt());
parsedObject = i;
```

I get the error in the subject line during runtime output by JUnit..  bb is a ByteBuffer and parsedObject is an Object. I am using Java 7 and my coworker and I are stumped as to what the problem is.

Any ideas?

Comment: please show us your whole stack trace and your whole test.

Comment: Is there a way to get junit to print the whole stack trace?  The test is a single call into this function.

Comment: Are you sure `parsedObject` is an `Object`? The error message indicates, that it is an `Object[]`, and you can't cast an `Integer` to an array type.

Comment: The deleration:        Object parsedObject = null;

Comment: Same error with explicit cast.

Comment: LOL. What type is `parsedObject`, as a comrade has already asked? It looks like it is of type `Object[]`, which can't be assigned from an Integer as per Java language regulations.

Comment: Nope, see previous comment showing the decleration.

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace to show where the error begins. It sounds like, by the time you're trying to read the integer from bb, you're actually reading an object array. Anyway, where are you reading from with bb?

Comment: Is there a way to get junit to print the whole stack trace?

Comment: The error is not coming from the above 3 lines.

Comment: i cant see the stack trace.. and use Integer.valueOf instead of new Integer, inneficient number constructor

Comment: If I comment out the line parsedObject = i the error does not happen.

Comment: Using Integer.valueOf also gives the same error.

Comment: @BurtonSamograd - If that's true, the above three lines are not what you REALLY have.

Comment: (Perhaps the error is coming from somewhere where you assign `parsedObject` to something else, further down in the code.)

Comment: That's why I asked for the stack trace. That will better tell us where the error is happening.

Comment: Burton, you suggested earlier (comment #2) that JUnit does not give you a stack trace. Does it give you one if you move the code into a `main` method?

Answer (score 2):

[Ljava.lang.Object; is the name for Object[]

You're trying to cast an Integer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates, that `parsedObject` is an `Object[]`, and you can't cast an Integer to an array type.

`Object` would be `java.lang.Object`

`Object[]` is `[Ljava.lang.Object`

Answer (score 0):

According to this [java: what is this: [Ljava.lang.Object;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object) your error says you are trying to cast to an Object[], not to an Object. So, as some people already told you, this is the problem, the cast from Integer to Object[] which is not permitted in Java. Please confirm that you are not using an Object[] in any place of your code that could affect this.

Comment: I put the decleration for parsedObject in the question.  It is an Object.

Comment: I am not talking about parsedObject. I already saw your comment on that. I am talking about checking it in general because this is what the error means.