# Does cometd allow you to publish arrays through JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, cometd

I have this JavaScript code:

```
$.cometd.publish('/service/slideshow/add_ids', {"list":[1889, 1888, 1887, 1886, 1885, 1884]});
```

In my Java code I have:

```
         Map<String,Object> data = message.getDataAsMap();
        if(data.containsKey("list"))
        {
            JSONObject o1 = new JSONObject(data);
            String idList = o1.toString();
        }
```

and my string 'idList' ends up being:

```
{"list":"[Ljava.lang.Object;@41c271b8"}
```

I have successfully published non-arrays and parsed them out correctly, but I can't seem to get arrays to work.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is it not supported?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's the default `toString()` output of an array of object. You may be better off iterating through the array, or else publishing `java.util.Arrays.toString(o1)`

Comment: Check out [java: what is this: \[Ljava.lang.Object;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object) for more on this.

Comment: Thanks that helped explain what I am seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `JSONArray` instead.

```
Map<String, Object> data = message.getDataAsMap();
if(data.containsKey("list"))
{
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data.get("list"));
    String idList = ja.toString();
}
```