# Apps script to get automated html email on google form submit

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to send a confirmation email whenever a customer submit a booking via google form. The content of the email will be partly based on the number of people and timeslot the customer chosen.
I succeed in triggering an email, but the email content is [object Object]. What did i do wrong?

```
function sendBookingConfirmationEmail(e) {

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("confirmationEmail.html");
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var bookingParameters = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var bookingName = bookingParameters[0].getResponse()
  var numberOfTele = bookingParameters[1].getResponse()
  var numberOfKids = bookingParameters[2].getResponse()
  var numberOfAdults = bookingParameters[3].getResponse()
  var scheduledSlot = bookingParameters[4].getResponse()

  html.numberOfKids = numberOfKids;
  html.numberOfAdults = numberOfAdults;
  html.numberOfTele = numberOfTele;
  html.scheduledSlot = scheduledSlot;

  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();

  var emailSubject = "BOOKING CONFIRMATION";
  var options = { htmlBody: htmlText }

  if (emailTo !== undefined) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, emailSubject, options);

  }

}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>  <?= numberOfKids ?> <?= numberOfAdults ?> Your booking has been confirmed.  etc...</p>

    <p> Best Regards<br>
    Team</p>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113813/sending-mail-with-html-body-using-for-in-google-apps-script), try changing this line

`GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, emailSubject, options);`

to

`GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, emailSubject, "", options);`

I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) ,the full signature for the function is the folowing :

`sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`

I supsect that you pass the options variable as the body

As workaround, you can put every argument into an object :

`sendEmail({recipient:emailTo , subject: emailSubject, htmlBody: htmlText})`

Comment: It seems doesnt work, Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.sendEmail.
    at sendBookingConfirmationEmail(Code:25:14). I changed my code as follow   `if (emailTo !== undefined) {GmailApp.sendEmail({recipient:emailTo, subject: emailSubject, htmlBody: htmlText})`

Comment: damn ! if you usie `JSON.stringify(htmlTExt)`

Comment: `var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
var newText = JSON.stringify(htmlText)

  if (emailTo !== undefined) { GmailApp.sendEmail({recipient:emailTo, subject: emailSubject, htmlBody: newText})`
still doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, and with : GmailApp.sendEmail({recipient:emailTo, subject: emailSubject, body:"", htmlBody: htmlText})

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply but sorry still doesnt work

Comment: Okay then with a consol.log(htmlText) what do you got ?