# Titan's IllegalArgumentException on Graph creation

Tags: java, configuration, titan, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm getting an initialization error when I try to instantiate my graph in blueprints. Here's the code that I'm using to create a new graph:

```
String path = "conf/titan-cassandra-" + System.getProperty("env") + ".properties";
Graph graph = TitanFactory.open(path);
```

The system property is being set and the file exists. The error is being thrown in TitanFactory:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(" + 
Pattern.quote(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_NS.getName()) + "\\..*" + "(" + 
Pattern.quote(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_DIRECTORY.getName()) + "|" + 
Pattern.quote(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_CONF_FILE.getName()) + ")" + "|" + 
Pattern.quote(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_NS.getName()) + "\\..*" + "(" + 
Pattern.quote(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_DIRECTORY.getName()) + "|" + 
Pattern.quote(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_CONF_FILE.getName()) + ")" + ")");
```

Evaluating the expression GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_NS yields 'null'. Why might this be?

Edit:

I'm including the stack trace as well

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.containsAny(Ljava/lang/String;[C)Z
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.ConfigElement.<init>(ConfigElement.java:26)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.ConfigNamespace.<init>(ConfigNamespace.java:19)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.ConfigNamespace.<init>(ConfigNamespace.java:24)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<clinit>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:81)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.getLocalConfiguration(TitanFactory.java:240)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.getLocalConfiguration(TitanFactory.java:170)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:61)
    at io.fama.api.service.GraphHolder.populateGraph(GraphHolder.java:28)
    at io.fama.api.service.GraphHolder.graph(GraphHolder.java:21)
    at io.fama.api.DebugTests.main(DebugTests.java:7)
```

When maven runs the test it throws a different error. This one looks like it's related to dependencies.

Comment: What does your System.getProperty("env") resolve to?

Comment: dev, test, or prod depending on my environment. I'm running some tests, so it is 'test'; the relative path is 'conf/titan-cassandra-test.properties'.

Comment: Does this give a stack trace of any sort, or just the exception with no other information?

Comment: I just added the stack trace to the question.

Comment: What Titan version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the stack trace, but it is easily reproducible from the Gremlin shell. When running `gremlin.sh`, it is usually best to run it from the $TITAN_HOME directory, not $TITAN_HOME/bin.

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-test.properties')
Backend shorthand unknown: conf/titan-cassandra-test.properties
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Backend shorthand unknown: conf/titan-cassandra-test.properties
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:120)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.getLocalConfiguration(TitanFactory.java:175)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:61)
```

You need to watch out for the relative path. Most likely you are running the program from a different directory such that the relative path to the properties file does not resolve. Either run the program from the correct parent directory or use an absolute path.

Comment: @cscan Thanks for adding your stack trace. This answer doesn't apply.

Comment: Turns out there were two issues, one was from the wrong version of a dependency being included and the other being that maven was running the code from a different path.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception leads to this line of code:

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(!StringUtils.containsAny(name, ILLEGAL_CHARS),"Name contains illegal character: %s (%s)",name,ILLEGAL_CHARS);
```

We can see in the Illegal Characters declaration:

```
public static final char[] ILLEGAL_CHARS = new char[]{SEPARATOR,' ','\t','#','@','<','>','?','/',';','"','\'',':','+','(',')','*','^','`','~','$','%','|','\\','{','[',']','}'};
```

This line in the constructor of the [ConfigElement](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.thinkaurelius.titan/titan-core/0.5.4/com/thinkaurelius/titan/diskstorage/configuration/ConfigElement.java#ConfigElement.0SEPARATOR)(Line 18) abstract class prevents any of the following characters from being in the path.

```
Tabs, New Line characters, # @ < > ? / ; " ' : + ( ) * ^ ` ~ $ % | \ { [ ] } and the .
```

So the issue is not an absolute/relative path issue.

However, the error you are getting is related to the .containsAny method on StringUtils. From what I can gather, it's throwing up that error because the [Preconditions checkState methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/15.0/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#Preconditions.checkArgument%28boolean%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)(Line 172) do not have a valid call for [all four of the parameters given.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.thinkaurelius.titan/titan-core/0.5.1/com/thinkaurelius/titan/diskstorage/configuration/ConfigElement.java)(Line 26). This leads me to believe that you will get this error because no check can be done since no method is available to be used.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object) helpful because it helped me understand what the

```
Ljava/lang/String;[C)Z
```

On the end of the first line of your stack-trace specifically meant. 
No method exists in the StringUtils package that this Titan package is attempting to call, and will throw this NoSuchMethodError until a method that handles all FOUR of the parameters is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the absolute path for the properties file solved the issue for me.