# Populate ListView with ArrayList having String array as elements

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-listview

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lst_layout, R.id.lstLayout, exList);
                lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                lstView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

exList is the ArayList of String arrays. How to populate ListView with it?

```
exList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Edit starts here. It's in asynctask created here asdad asd asd asdasada sdada daasd asd ad asda dasd asd asda da dasdasd asdasd ad :

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String[] temp = new String[4];
            try {
                InputStream stream = downloadUrl("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
                try {
                    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                    xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                    int kontrol = 0;
                    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {


                            if (xpp.getName().equals("Currency")) {
                                kontrol++;
                                //ExchangeRate exr = new ExchangeRate();
                                //exr.setCurrencyCode(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "CurrencyCode"));
                                temp[0] = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "CurrencyCode");
                                Log.d("deneme: ", xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "CurrencyCode"));

                            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Isim") && xpp.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                                kontrol++;
                                //ExchangeRate exr = exList.get(exList.size() - 1);
                                //exr.setCurrencyName(xpp.getText());
                                temp[1] = xpp.getText();
                                Log.d("deneme", xpp.getText());

                            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("ForexBuying") && xpp.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                                kontrol++;
                                //ExchangeRate exr = exList.get(exList.size() - 1);
                               //exr.setForexBuying(Double.valueOf(xpp.getText()));
                                temp[2] = xpp.getText();
                                Log.d("deneme", xpp.getText());
                            }else if (xpp.getName().equals("ForexSelling") && xpp.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                                kontrol++;
                                //ExchangeRate exr = exList.get(exList.size() - 1);
                                //exr.setForexBuying(Double.valueOf(xpp.getText()));
                                temp[3] = xpp.getText();
                                Log.d("deneme", xpp.getText());
                            }
                            if (kontrol == 4) {
                                exList.add(temp);
                                temp = new String[4];
                                kontrol=0;
                            }
                        }
                        eventType = xpp.next();
                    }

                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return "";

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: give proper justification to problem you are facing

Comment: when i lauch the app, i see [Ljava.lang.String;@354.... in listview. not the string elements of string array inside array list.

Comment: Show your code for `exList` please.

Comment: Please add more code specially where you are creating `exList`

Comment: Your edit demonstrates the problem - you are creating an `ArrayList` of `String[]`, not `String`. You are seeing the [internal form of the Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object), which isn't useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handled it using custom adapter as suggested. Here is the adapter:

```
package com.xxx.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OzelAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<String[]> mKisiListesi;

    public OzelAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String[]> kisiler) {
        //XML'i alıp View'a çevirecek inflater'ı örnekleyelim
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //gösterilecek listeyi de alalım
        mKisiListesi = kisiler;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mKisiListesi.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //şöyle de olabilir: public Object getItem(int position)
        return mKisiListesi.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View satirView;

        satirView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lst_layout, null);
        TextView textView1 =
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.lstLayout1);
        TextView textView2 =
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.lstLayout2);
        TextView textView3 =
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.lstLayout3);
        TextView textView4 =
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.lstLayout4);

        textView1.setText(mKisiListesi.get(position)[0]);
        textView2.setText(mKisiListesi.get(position)[1]);
        textView3.setText(mKisiListesi.get(position)[2]);
        textView4.setText(mKisiListesi.get(position)[3]);

        return satirView;
    }
}
```

Here is the layout row of the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:lines="8"
        android:id="@+id/lstLayout1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:editable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:lines="8"
        android:id="@+id/lstLayout2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:editable="false" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:lines="8"
        android:id="@+id/lstLayout3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:editable="false" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:lines="8"
        android:id="@+id/lstLayout4"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:editable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally:

```
OzelAdapter dataAdapter = new OzelAdapter(MainActivity.this, exList);
                lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                lstView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

To use a basic ArrayAdapter, you just need to initialize the adapter and attach the adapter to the ListView. First, we initialize the adapter:

```
ArrayList<String> exList = new ArrayList<>();
exList.add("data1");
exList.add("data2");
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exList);
```

The ArrayAdapter requires a declaration of the type of the item to be converted to a View (a String in this case) and then accepts three arguments: context (activity instance), XML item layout, and the array of data. Note that we've chosen simple_list_item_1.xml which is a simple TextView as the layout for each of the items.

Now, we just need to connect this adapter to a ListView to be populated:

```
ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lstView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I want to create ArrayList<String[]>. When i run it the way you advised, the result is the same.

Comment: why you have to use String[]. are you have to pass multiple data in your adapter?

Comment: If you have pass String[] to adapter then you have to make custom adapter for it. in simple adapter you can only pass String value

Answer (score 2):

To convert the elements of a `String[]` to an `ArrayList`, use the `Arrays.asList()` method:

```
String[] temp = new String[4];
//Assign value for each element in this array in doInBackground...
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

The `[Ljava.lang.String;@xxxx` you see is the internal form of your `String[]`. To [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object):

> If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the internal
>   form of the name consists of the name of the element type preceded by
>   one or more '[' characters representing the depth of the array
>   nesting [when `toString()` is called]. The encoding of element type names is as follows:
>
> ```
> Element Type        Encoding
> boolean             Z
> byte                B
> char                C
> double              D
> float               F
> int                 I
> long                J
> short               S 
> class or interface  Lclassname;
> ```

**Edit:**

```
String[] temp;
//temp is the String array returned from/populated in your doInBackground method.
List<String> exlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temp));
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lst_layout, R.id.lstLayout, exList);
                lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                lstView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: If i apply that, where exactly should i do it in the code i shared? And what else changes must be applied?

Comment: @gokturk That depends. Essentially, `ArrayAdapter` typically take a `List<String>` as its argument. You could even try passing your `String[]` directly, as there is an `ArrayAdapter` constructor that accepts a `T[] object` Argument: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, T[]) . I've added an edit to my answer though that should help.