# How do I convert [[Ljava.lang.String;@7defb4fb] to a String

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print the `String`, below is the code:

```
Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
for (Object obj : objArr)
{
    System.out.println(obj);
    cell.setValue(obj);
}
```

but I get following output in the console:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@7defb4fb]
```

I have tried the following snippets:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objArr));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList((objArr)));
System.out.println(objArr[k]);
```

But all of these are giving similar strange output:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@7defb4fb]
[[Ljava.lang.String;@7defb4fb]
[Ljava.lang.String;@7defb4fb
```

**How do I get the string value out of it?**

**

> Edit:

**
My problem was to print and array of an array in Java. First thing was to recognize that its nested arrays and hence when I try to iterate over the array and print its elements it was printing the address of the address instead of the element.

> [Ljava.lang.String;@7defb4fb]

My problem was to recognize this as an array and iterate over this array again in order to print the elements. Hence here was the solution

```
if (obj instanceof String[]) {
        String[] strArray = (String[]) obj;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
        // System.out.println(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Yes it gave me this output  [[Folder, TrackerDemo1, ckuser, released ]]. But again I need the individual elements in the array.This isnt much useful. I can apply string methods to extract each element but that will add additional Lines of Code to my source code

Comment: What type of object are you storing inside object array?

Comment: Cast it to `String` then. `String value = (String) obj;`

Comment: Casted and printed - _System.out.println((String) obj);_ recieve this output again _[Ljava.lang.String;@7defb4fb_

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: You could have simply used Arrays.deepToString, no need to go type of object using instance of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) and then **cast** it to `String[]`.

Sample code:

```
String[] strArr = {"anc", "asda"};
Object[] objArr = {strArr, strArr}; // Array of String Arrays
for (Object obj : objArr) {
    if (obj instanceof String[]) {
        String[] strArray = (String[]) obj;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
        // System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the array and print the strings one by one. If the individual objects are arrays, then you need to iterate them as well.

Comment: How do I check whether Individual Objects are arrays again? In my snippet its **Object obj**

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on **what kind of data you are adding to array**. Even if you iterate on array still printing object using **SOP** will call **`toString()`** method on the type class of the object.

So if you are adding objects of your own class then provide customized **`toString()`** method. And now iterate on array.

> [default implementation of object's toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) method will produce a string in following format   `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Best solution for your problem is use `Arrays.deepToString(objArray)` with custom toString() implementation if objArray contains objects of your defined class.

Look at the example below

```
public class ArrayPrint {
int age;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayPrint obj1 = new ArrayPrint ();
    obj1.age = 12;

    ArrayPrint obj2 = new ArrayPrint ();
    obj2.age = 15;

    ArrayPrint[] ageArr = {obj1, obj2};
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ageArr));

}

}
```

Output for this program shall be
`[sfo.ArrayPrint@19f953d, sfo.ArrayPrint@1fee6fc]`

But to get the actual content, if I override toString() method to my class like below

```
public String toString ()
{
    return ""+age;
}
```

You get the output as below

**[12,15]**

> So you see, Arrays.deepToString() shall be useful only if you have custom toString() implementation for your own class objects.

Comment: My Data is [[Folder, TrackerDemo1, ckuser, released ]] when I do Arrays.deepToString(objArr). How do I apply toString on this?

Comment: So here you just need to iterate on array and print if they all are just string

Comment: Can I do something directly with obj instead of again iterating over objArr. It involves additional lines of code.

Comment: @iQuestProgrammer   doesn't `Arrays.deepToString(objArr)` this work for you. Can you tell me what type of data is ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array and print each element.if the array element is array you need to iterate throw them as well you can do that by **reflection** or use **`instanceof`**

ex :- `if(obj instanceof int[])` or `if(obj instanceof String[])`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This is happening because `Arrays.toString()`is used on an array of objects which store separate elements and it fails when the array contains another array of objects within it, just like in your case. `deepToString` can be used to resolve this. I used `Arrays.deepToString(Object[])` to convert the array of objects to string and then worked on the resultant string to find specific fields. Check out the second paragraph of the answer provided by @polygenelubricants in [What is this: [Ljava.lang.Object;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/what-is-this-ljava-lang-object/65458439#65458439)

Check https://www.baeldung.com/java-tostring-array for more details on the solution.