# Can't get Object string value; need to convert to String to compare

Tags: java, swing, object, jtable, jtree

I want to check if the value does exist or not in `Tree` when trying to add node from `Tree`. The value does not match in the case that I got `Object` instead of `String`.

Here is the action code for calling `existsInTable()`

```
     try {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedElement = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) TestTree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
        Object[] row = {selectedElement};
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) myTests_table.getModel();

        if (selectedElement.isLeaf() == true && existsInTable(myTests_table, row) == false) {
            model.addRow(row);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Choose Test name!", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }
```

Here are the check method

```
    public boolean existsInTable(JTable table, Object[] testname) {
    int row = table.getRowCount();
       for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        String str = "";
        str = table.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        if (testname.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println(str);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data alreadyexist.", "message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

```
the result is this : [Ljava.lang.Object;@11da1f8     
but it should be   : Test
```

Comment: Thanks
The result is this : [Ljava.lang.Object;@11da1f8
but it should be : Test

Comment: You are printing the object in string format and not the any associated variable to the given object.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an instance of `Object` to your `TableModel`, that is what `getValueAt()` will return. Given an `Object`, the result returned by [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) is entirely expected—"a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object."

Looking closer, you appear to have added an [array of `Object` instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3442090/230513). Given a default table model,

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(1, 1);
```

the following lines

```
model.setValueAt(new Object[1], 0, 0);
System.out.println(model.getValueAt(0, 0));
```

produce this output:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@330bedb4
```

To see a string, such as "Test", add a corresponding instance of `String` to your `TableModel`:

```jave
model.setValueAt("Test", 0, 0);
System.out.println(model.getValueAt(0, 0));
```

which produces the desired output:

```
Test
```

For best results, verify that your implementation of `getColumnClass()` is compatible, as suggested in [*How to Use Tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: Thanks for reply,,, actually my date comes from DB, could u please make this command clear 
model.setValueAt("Test", 0, 0);    
How to use it with daynamic data

Comment: Because they are are conveniently `Comparable`, use `java.sql.Date`; here are some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=java.sql.date).