# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; incompatible with java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, object, dictionary, casting

I'm doing the following

```
 String s = caseInsensitiveMap.get("buyerCode");
```

and I'm getting the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; incompatible with java.lang.String
```

I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Googling the answer seems to point towards needing to use a `String[]` somewhere, but I have no idea where.

More relevent information:

> **caseInsensitiveMap** : Map caseInsensitiveMap - com.msw.commerce.me.commands.MSWOrgCmdImpl.setRequestProperties(TypedProperty)
>
> **.get()** : String java.util.Map.get(Object key)

I have also attempted to do

```
String s = caseInsensitiveMap.get((Object) "buyerCode");
```

to explicitly cast the string `"buyerCode"` to it's needed Object type, but I get the same error.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  From what I can see, I'm matching all of the types here.  `.get()` takes an Object, and I'm giving it an object.  It returns a String, and I'm assigning it to a String.

---

Edit:  more code

```
public void setRequestProperties(TypedProperty reqProperties)
        throws ECException {
    Map<String, String> reqMap = reqProperties.getMap();
    Map<String, String> caseInsensitiveMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(
            String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    caseInsensitiveMap.putAll(reqMap);
```

Here are the docs for [TypedProperty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/com/ibm/commerce/datatype/TypedProperty.html)

Comment: Show us the relevant code. How is caseInsensitiveMap declared, initialized and populated?

Comment: [Ljava.lang.String means String[], in other words, you are getting an array of Strings, which is not the same as a single String. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object

Comment: Your map contains a `String[]` as the value instead of the `String` you are expecting. Maps can generally contain any type of object and in your case, you are inserting the wrong type without realizing it.

Comment: Based on the error message, `caseInsensitiveMap.get()` is returning an array of Strings, not a String. Without your code, it's impossible to analyze further.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  doing String[] s = ... gives me compilation errors

Comment: Do you get any warning at the line `Map<String, String> reqMap = reqProperties.getMap();`?

Comment: @Eran no warnings there

Comment: What does `getMap()` method of `TypedProperty` return?

Comment: You using this [TypedProperty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/com/ibm/commerce/datatype/TypedProperty.html)?

Comment: @Eran Map com.ibm.commerce.datatype.TypedProperty.getMap()

Comment: Well, based on the [TypedProperty Javadoc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/com/ibm/commerce/datatype/TypedProperty.html), the `Map` returned by `getMap` may contain non-String values (including String arrays), so assigning it to a `Map<String,String>` is unsafe, and allows the exception you got to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost a certainty that TypedProperty.getMap() is *heterogeneous*.  It's really a map from String keys to Objects, and it's therefore unsafe to assign it to a variable of type `Map< String, String >`.  If you aren't getting a warning at the line

```
Map<String, String> reqMap = reqProperties.getMap();
```

it's probably because the warnings about unchecked conversions are disabled in your development environment.

The problem is not the type of the key; the problem is the type of the *value* you're trying to add to your TreeMap.  You can't cast an array of String to a String, so `putAll()` is going to fail.

Try declaring your TreeMap as

```
Map<String, Object> reqMap = reqProperties.getMap();
Map<String, Object> caseInsensitiveMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>(
        String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: You were correct.  Whoever wrote the code that set `caseInsensitiveMap` (as well as myself) did not realize that TypedProperties in no way guarantee <String, String>.