# Why is an array of classes loaded automatically in Java?

Tags: java

I created a java agent class, that just uses [java.lang.Instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses--) to retrieve an array of classes, over which I iterate, and print their full names.

I used this command to run this agent:

`java -javaagent:<agent_jar> -jar <sample_jar>`

`<agent_jar>` contains my agent class, and `<sample_jar>` just contains a class with an empty main method (since I have to pass **some** class/jar to the `java` command)

So, basically, it printed all the default classes loaded by the JVM, and here's a snippet for class names containing 'String' and 'Object' in their names:

(Output format: Class.getName() - Class.getTypeName())

```
java.util.Objects - java.util.Objects
[Ljava.lang.String; - java.lang.String[]
java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator - java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator
[Ljava.io.ObjectStreamField; - java.io.ObjectStreamField[]
java.io.ObjectStreamField - java.io.ObjectStreamField
[Ljava.lang.Object; - java.lang.Object[]
java.lang.StringBuilder - java.lang.StringBuilder
java.lang.StringBuffer - java.lang.StringBuffer
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder - java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder
java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject - java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject
java.lang.String - java.lang.String
java.lang.Object - java.lang.Object
```

Why are there array entries for many classes, eg. Object and Object[]?

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object

Comment: Just because your `main` is empty, it doesn't mean that the JVM does *nothing*. It obviously needs to load some stuff to be able to load your class and to run your main method.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be loaded because every class in Java is extends `Object` class or we can say Object is a superclass of every class in Java.

So when you print out the loaded classes, it will show the `Object` class.

From Oracle Docs:

> The Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the
>   class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect,
>   of the Object class. Every class you use or write inherits the
>   instance methods of Object.

From [here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html):

Class Loaders

> In a JVM, each and every class is loaded by some instance of a
>   java.lang.ClassLoader. The ClassLoader class is located in the
>   java.lang package and developers are free to subclass it to add their
>   own functionality to class loading.
>
> **Whenever a new JVM is started by typing java MyMainClass, the "bootstrap class loader" is responsible for loading key Java classes
>   like java.lang.Object and other runtime code into memory first.** The
>   runtime classes are packaged inside of the JRE\lib\rt.jar file. We
>   cannot find the details of the bootstrap class loader in the Java
>   documentation, since this is a native implementation. For the same
>   reason, the behavior of the bootstrap class loader will also differ
>   across JVMs.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are there array entries for many classes, eg. Object and Object[]?

It is just classes that you application, and/or the JVM's default application launcher code reference.

The `Object` class will be loaded because other other classes inherit from it.  The `Object[]` array type is most likely used when the launcher uses reflection to find the `Method` object for the `main(String[])` method.

There is a bunch of "black magic" happens behinds the scenes when a JVM bootstraps itself.  If you *really* need to know, then the source code is available ....

(It is also possible that your agent's classes and dependencies will show up in the list, but they may also be loaded by a distinct classloader.)

Answer (score 0):

If you call `main(String[] args)` you'll need `Object` (because everything extends `Object`), `String[]` and `String` already.

Now take a look at the imports of `String`, you'll recognize a few:

```
import java.io.ObjectStreamField;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;
```

Classes are not loaded right away just because they are imported. But when you call the `main` method, the JVM does some processing before, e.g. the parsing of parameters and writing them to the `args` array. It's not hard to imagine that some of the classes you listed are needed for that.