# Retrieve data from org.wso2.siddhi.core.event.Event class

Tags: java, siddhi

I have an output stream whose definition is 
   define stream outStream (deviceID string, val int).

In the 'receive' method of its callback, I want to do some processing with the val(of type int). Is there any method to retrieve this integer value from the Event object?

I tried to retrieve it using "events[i].getData().toString()", but the string returned is "[Ljava.lang.Object;@c55cfc" and i can't make any sense of it. (Here, 'events' is the array of 'Events' passed in to the 'receive' method of the callback)

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java: what is this: \[Ljava.lang.Object;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object)

Answer (score 1):

`getData()` method of `Event` class returns an `Object[]`. That means, you'll be calling `toString()` on an `Object[]`. In Java, that'll print the class name + hashcode of the object (`Ljava.lang.Object;@c55cfc`) (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442100/1805178) for more info). So, if you need to get the values instead, simply iterate through the `Object[]` returned by `getData()` method. (i.e `events[i].getData()[j]`)