# Unable to execute for loop

Tags: java

I'm new to java and just wrote a program for learning purpose.
I have two arrays of strings and i want to compare the length of both string arrays.If lengths are equal then compare the values of each first string array with the values of each second array .If value got matched then print that value.
Not able to rectify where the problem is ?

```
     package com.equal.arrat;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

       public class ArrayEqual {
         public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s[] = {"anuj","kr","chaurasia"};
        String s1[] = {"anuj","kr","chaurasia"};

        if (s.length==s1.length)
        {
            System.out.println(s.length);
            for (int i =0 ; i>=s.length;i++)
            {
                for (int j =0 ;j>=s1.length;j++)
                {
                System.out.println("test");
                if (s[i].equals(s1[j]))
                {
                System.out.println("ok" + s[i]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("not ok");
                    }
        }
        }
       }
        else{
            System.out.println("Length Not Equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have errors in your `for` loop condition checks. This line -

```
for (int i = 0; i >= s.length; i++)
```

should be changed to this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
```

Similarly, change this line -

```
for (int j = 0; j >= s1.length; j++)
```

to this -

```
for (int j = 0; j < s1.length; j++)
```

Comment: Using `<=` means that it will also execute with `i == s.length` which is out of bounds.

Comment: @FatalError: Sorry, forgot to remove the `=` part. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Downvoter: A comment is usually helpful to correct the mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

Incorrect logic used. What you meant was `<` instead of `>=`

```
for (int i =0 ; i>=s.length;i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i =0 ; i<s.length;i++)
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: @Littlebird just check if two array contains same elements or not. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897366/comparing-two-array-in-java

Comment: Downvoter... Please leave a comment so that it helps to understand the missing point if any.

Answer (score 3):

At first you are saying `i` and `j` is 0 then checking in for loop that if it is greater than `s.length` or not which is false so it's not executing. Try

```
for (int i =0 ; i<s.length;i++)
{
    for (int j =0 ;j<s1.length;j++)
    {
```

Comment: code **i<=s.length** and **j<=s1.length** is incorrect. You should use j< s1.length and i < s.length instead.

Answer (score 2):

your comparators are off in the for loops. That may be why its not working

```
if (s.length==s1.length)
{
    System.out.println(s.length);
    for (int i =0 ; i<s.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j =0 ;j<s1.length;j++)
        {
        System.out.println("test");
        if (s[i].equals(s1[j]))
        {
        System.out.println("ok" + s[i]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok");
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i =0 ; i>=s.length;i++)
```

On first iteration `i=0` and `s.length=3` and `i>=s.length` would translate to `0>=3` which is false and hence the loop will not execute.  It should be `i<=s.length`

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare the length of both string arrays.If lengths are equal then compare the values of each first string array with the values of each second array .so you cant use this  `>=` for comparing length.

simply try it

```
 for (int i =0 ; i<s.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j =0 ;j<s1.length;j++)
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are not correct. Try

```
   for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<s1.length; j++)
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

change `for (int i =0 ; i>=s.length;i++)` to

```
for (int i =0 ; i<s.length;i++)
```

and same for inner loop

because your first condition itself is not getting satisfied
i=0 and you are checking if i>=s.length(means 3 in this case)

so your for loop will not be executed