# java comparing values in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Wasn't sure whether to make a new thread or not. but i'll post it here. I figured my explanation was not very good.

i have a class below

lets say int[] = 1204, 1205

```
public class Job {

 private  int[] serviceCode =;     

 public Job (int[] jobCode) {


serviceCode = jobCode;
```

}

```
  public  int[] getJobCode() {
    return serviceCode;
 }
```

and this is the main program

```
public class MainProgram { 

public static void main {



}
```

}

how do i put the values of the array into separate integers?

Comment: disk space is cheap, use meaningful variable names!

Comment: you can't just simply say h==t, because h is array and t is an integer...

Comment: Please explain clearly what you mean by "I'm trying to compare values from `int[] h` to `int t`".  Which values?  All of them?  Are you trying to see if every value in the array equals `t`, or if any value in the array equals `t`, or the first value in the array equals `t`, or what?????

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation. i have edited my question that will help with my problem. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly compare an `int[]` to an `int`. You need to access a value in the array and then compare.

```
int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};
int value = 1;
if (myArray[0] == value) {/*do something*/}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare an array with a variable that holds just one data.

You know, array is a data structure.

You must loop through the array and then compare each value of the array with `t`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {

    if( t == h[i] ) // Or any other comparison operator
        /* Perform some action.*/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `int[] h` is an array of integers while `int t` is just a integer variable. So comparison is not at all possible. As per your question's title `java comparing values in arrays` [here is an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897366/comparing-two-integer-arrays-in-java)

Either you can check whether this value exist in an array in `for` loop.

```
int val = 1;
int[] valArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i = 0; i < valArray.length ; i++)
{
     if (valArray[i] == val)
       {// Matched
       }
     else
      { // Not matched
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array is contiguous memory location, in order to get the specific values from the each addressable unit you have to access that addressable location.
Suppose you declare an array like this.

```
int[] array = {10,20,30};
```

This will do the memory allocation like this: ( lets `0th` element is at address `100` and assuming int size is of `4 byte`)

```
index        0      1      2
         -----------------------
         |  10  |  20   |  30   |
         -----------------------
address:    100    104    108
```

Array `array` name is basically base address form where the array starts in this case it is `100`, next element will be present at `104` and `108`.

Now lets say we have an integer variable : `int temp=100`. Now to compare  array element with integer variable `temp`, we have to access the each element of `array` of type integer situated at specific index.  You have to compare like following:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(temp>array[i])  /*array[i] is accessing the value at index i"*/ 
           //do something
    else
          //do something.
}
```