# How to check if my array is not the same as the original?

Tags: java, arrays, equals

***IN JAVA***
I have an array like the fallowing:

```
int[] board={0,0,0}
```

If I change it to something like:

```
board[1,2,3]
```

I want to check if my current board is equal to the previous board:

```
if (board[0,0,0] != board[1,2,10]){
   System.out.print("Its full")
}
```

And I want to get if it's right or wrong.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14897467/822870
Although your question is not very clear. What does for example `board[1,2,3]` mean?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a copy of the original array in order to be able to compare it to the new state of the array.

The comparison itself can be done with

```
Arrays.equals(originalArray, currentArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the elements individually.  Loop through one array comparing to values of other array:

```
boolean same = true;
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
{
   if(board[i] != board2[i]
   {
      same = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

if same is true then they are the same if not then they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Arrays` class:

```
if(!Arrays.equals(board1, board2))// check whether boeard1 and boeard2 contains the same elements
   System.out.print("Its full")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Arrays class from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html.

```
boolean equals = Arrays.equals(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there is a utility class called Arrays, which has an equals() overloaded method that you can use to compare if two arrays have the same values in each position.

Check the [Oracle Documentation about Arrays.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int[],%20int[]%29)