# Finding the difference and storing it in a new array?

Tags: java

I am writing a program here that takes two int[] arrays and subtracts each element from each other and stores the result in a new array.

this sounds pretty sound and i know my math is right seeing as its simple subtraction..

my method is here,

```
public int[] diff(int[] nums1, int[] nums2)
    {
        int[] diffArray = new int [nums1.length];
        int tempValue = 0;
        int tempValue2 = 0;
        int subtract = 0;


        if (nums1.length != nums2.length)
        {
            diffArray = new int[0];
        }

        else
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < nums1.length && i < nums2.length; ++i)
            {
                tempValue = nums1[i];
                tempValue2 = nums2[i];
                System.out.println("temp value 1: " + tempValue); //just me trying to debug
                System.out.println("temp value 2: " + tempValue2); //just me trying to debug

                subtract = tempValue2 - tempValue;
                System.out.println("Subtracted :" + subtract); //just me trying to debug

                diffArray[i] = subtract;


            }
        }

        return diffArray;
    }
```

to test this i wrote a couple small pieces of code in my driver class.

The problem is, i made those 3 debug print statements in my for loop to see if i had the right numbers and everything is correct it just seems like its not storing it in diffArray?

for example,

```
   //Array of 1 element each : r(0)
            givenArray = new int[] {4};
            givenArray2 = new int[] {4};
            diffValue = srvObj.diff(givenArray, givenArray2);
            result = (diffValue == new int[] {0}) ? PASS : FAIL;
            System.out.println(testNum + ": " + result);
            ++testNum;

   //Array of multi-elements each that are diff : r({6, 10, 37})
            givenArray = new int[] {4, 5, 3};
            givenArray2 = new int[] {10, 15, 30};
            diffValue = srvObj.diff(givenArray, givenArray2);
            result = (diffValue == new int[] {6, 10, 37}) ? PASS : FAIL;
            System.out.println(testNum + ": " + result);
            ++testNum;
```

note : i am subtracting array2 from array1 not the other way.

however i keep getting FAIL every time? i can see in my print statements its done the math for each element

Surely there must be a problem when i try to give diffArray[i] the resulted subtraction?

Comment: Have you printed out the contents of your array, my suspicion is that the problem is in the test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java (and a lot of other languages), arrays are objects, so `==` won't work to compare them. It compares the *references*, so it checks if they're the same object, not whether they contain the same elements:

```
int[] a = new int[] {1,2,3};
a == a; //true
int[] b = new int[] {1,2,3};
a == b; //false
```

There's a method, though, [Arrays.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int[],%20int[]%29), that can compare them:

```
result = Arrays.equals(diffValue, new int[] {0}) ? PASS : FAIL;
```

You need to import Arrays at the beginning of your program, though:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

It looks like your `diff()` is working, though.

Comment: hm when i do something like implementing result = Array.equals(diffValue, new int[] {0}) ? PASS : FAIL; it seems to still pass FAIL. for instance diffValue = {0} will be the result of giving a1 ={4} and a2 = {4}; which is {0} but it still fails after i have added result = Array.equals(diffValue, new int[] {0}) ? PASS : FAIL; @KSFT

Comment: @ErikVorcov Try printing `diffValue` to make sure it's `{0}`.

Comment: interesting, i wouldve thought maybe arrays was imported for you, and good idea

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for array equality incorrectly here (and your other tests):

```
    result = (diffValue == new int[] {0}) ? PASS : FAIL;
```

In Java the `==` operator checks for *reference equality* when applied to objects, and the new array you create in this statement will never be the same object as `diffValue`.

What you need to do is to use the `equals()` method in the `Arrays` class, which checks for *value equality*.

A quick example:

```
    int[] arr1 = { 0 };
    int[] arr2 = { 0 };
    System.out.println(arr1 == arr2);               // false
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2));  // true
```

Comment: Why was this accepted? It's almost the same as my answer, but older.

Comment: its equally accepted, if i could accept them both i would. I just vibe with your description more

Answer (score -1):

Your test condition is wrong - `diffValue == new int[] {6, 10, 37}` will always resolve to `false` because the Java equality operator checks that the two variables are REALLY the same thing, not simply equivalent. Please see [Comparing two integer arrays in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14897366/823470) for ideas on comparing int arrays.

Comment: This is wrong. It won't always resolve to `true`. In fact, it will always resolve to `false`, because `diffValue` can't be the same object as the new int array being created. What do you mean by "REALLY the same thing, not simply equivalent"?

Comment: I made a mistake leaving that word unchanged when I was rewriting the answer (had changed "never resolve to true" to "always resolve to false"). Thank you for correcting me.