# compare multiple Integer arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to compare two Array Ints.

This is what I have so far:

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);            
        int [] lottery_number = new int[49];    
        int i;     
        int a = 0;
        for (i=0; i<lottery_number.length; i++){
            lottery_number[i]=i+1;
        }

        System.out.println("Please insert 6 numbers");     
        int [] Number = new int [6];    
        Number[0] = input.nextInt();
        Number[1] = input.nextInt();
        Number[2] = input.nextInt();
        Number[3] = input.nextInt();
        Number[4] = input.nextInt();     
        Number[5] = input.nextInt(); 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to compare the user input to certain Lottery_number array.

Comment: There is no comparison anywhere in your code. What have you tried? Also, use proper java naming conventions in the future

Comment: So, first off, its convention to have variables start with a lower case letter, so I would suggest making it number instead of Number. Just FYI

Second: could you please clarify what you are comparing for? In what circumstance would the comparison be a success of a failure?

Comment: I can believe that you *want* to compare two arrays in some way.  Your code shows no evidence of "trying to compare", however.

Comment: You need 2 arrays: real numbers vs expected numbers. Then go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897366/comparing-two-integer-arrays-in-java

Comment: Well, is number some weird Wrapper class? Based on the comments not likely but aside from that, u enter 6 numbers, and what? You have 49 lottery #'s from 0-48, if they enter a number in that range you want to tell the user they won?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MohamedSalad if it were a wrapper class it wouldn't have `int` for a prefix but rather be `Number[] arrayName`

Comment: Sorry it seems i have not explaned properly what my aim is to create a programme which compares certain arrays for example "Array 1,3,5,8,9,6" to the users 6 numbers. if they are correct then a if statement prints that they are correct or else it is uncorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I point out that I'm not sure of what you are asking, but it makes no sense to compare the lottery numbers array (all natural numbers from 1 to 50) with the player picks array (6 random numbers from 1 to 50.
Using the static method

```
Arrays.equals(int[] array1, int[] array2)
```

will return whether the arguments are equals (same number of elements, same value) but eventually this is not the case. Sorry if I have completely misunderstood what you asked.

Answer (score -1):

`numberInCommon` is a variable that says how many numbers the arrays have in common. I hope this is what you're looking for. You have to import `java.util.Arrays`

```
List lotteryNumbers = Arrays.asList(lottery_numbers);
int numbersInCommon = 0;
for(int i : Number){
    if(lotteryNumbers.contains(new Integer(i)))
        numbersInCommon++;
}
```

EDIT: You'll also need change
`int [] lottery_number = new int[49];` to
`Integer [] lottery_number = new Integer[49];`