# how to compare multiple arrays?

Tags: java

I need to compare rm.rel object array with agent array and also object array .i dont know how to perform it ? whether i need to store agent and object as some thing like arraylist or hashmap..

here is my code...
 The rm.rel array consist of values like
(mod
pur
and
agt
agt
and
obj
obj
mod
mod
mod
man
agt
cob
mod
obj
obj
agt
man
cnt
agt)

```
public String[] agent={"agt","cag","aoj","cao","ptn"};
public String[] object={ "obj", "cob", "opl", "ben"};
public void compare()

  {
      temp=new String[rm.length]; 
      for(int k=0;k<rm.length;k++)
      {
                   temp[k]=rm[k].rel[k];

      }
      for(int i=0;i<rm.length;i++)
      {
       for(int j=0;j<agent.length+object .length;j++)
          {
          if(temp[i].equals(agent[j]))
          {
              temp[i]="agent";
          }
          else if(temp[i].equals(object[j])) // It shows arrayout of bound exception
          {
              temp[i]=rm[i].rel[i];
          }
      }
      }
      for(int k=0;k<temp.length;k++)
      {
          System.out.println(temp[k]);
      }
  }
```

i need to compare each element of rm.rel array with all elements of agent array if it is not equal then it should compare with object array
pls help

Comment: What are you trying to compare for? If the two arrays both have the same values?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? What is the objective? Probably not order. Find the intersection?

Comment: Explain your problem more. It's not clear.

Comment: Regarding the exception: you access object[j] where j ranges from 0 to  agent.length+object.length so it gets out of the object array size

Comment: This is patent gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(temp[i].equals(object[j])) // It shows arrayout of bound exception
```

Don't want personally to be "Captain Obvious", but it's a good idea to check an index vs the array length before trying to access array item by index. For example:

```
if((object.length > j) && (temp[i].equals(object[j])))
```

And yes, use "Array.equals()" to compare arrays, as @Prateek proposed before.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what you're actually trying to compare for, I can tell you why you're geting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoudsException`. Your problem is here

```
for(int j = 0; j < agent.length + object.length; j++)
```

`j` will increment up to the size of both arrays combined, but max index for `object` is 3. Same with the `agent` array. `j` cannot be accesed passed 5.

Currently you have the loop looping up to 4 + 5 (9).

Answer (score 1):

Try this because your `compare` method is void. You just try to see if they are equal or not.

```
Arrays.sort(agent);
Arrays.sort(object)
boolean isEql = Arrays.equals(agent, object);
```

if array are equal it will return `true` otherwise `false`.

According to Java doc:

*Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order*

1. **[Arrays.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)** Returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. Two objects e1 and e2 are considered equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`. In other words, the two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null.
2. **[Arrays.deepEquals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)** Returns true if the two specified arrays are deeply equal to one another. `Unlike the equals(Object[],Object[])` method, this method is appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.

How `deepEquals` work see this example by [@polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2721042/1328612)?

Comment: Arrays.sort modifies the argument. It returns void.

Comment: i need to compare each element of rm.rel  array with all elements of agent array if it is not equal then it should compare with object array

Comment: @user2942551 The problem is, you haven't showed us your m.rel array, so we can't help you solve your problem.

Comment: @Boann thanks for the valid comments I edited the answer