# compare 2 2Dimensional arrays - Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, compare

Why isn't this true?

```
int[][] arrayOfSets = {{1,2},{9,10},{1,2},{3,5}};
int[][] test =        {{1,2},{9,10},{1,2},{3,5}};

if(arrayOfSets==test){ //{{1,2},{9,10},{1,2},{3,5}}){
   System.out.println("Exactly the same");
}
```

The output should be "Exactly the same". or how can I compare 2 variables with 2dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `==` thats why failed, it's for identical of object check so use :

```
boolean check = Arrays.deepEquals(arrayOfSets, test);
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare multidimensional arrays, use .deepEquals  The link explains why

[.deepEquals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14897467/2483830)

And the following link explains why == or .equals doesn't work.

[.equals definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2721042/2483830)

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because == compares the reference ie you can think of that as memory address..In this case since you are declaring 2 different arrays, their addresses are bound to be different.

One small suggestion
since your array doesn't contain consecutive numbers such as {1,2}, {1,3} similarly.... 
you can instead use objects with 2 instance numbers and put those objects inside an array